# Join three tables with JOIN and HABTM association

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 table items, characteristics, item_to_characteristics which item_to_characteristics is a middle table which keeps the HABTM association between 2 tables (items <-> characteristics).

item table has **id|title|description**

characteristic table has **id|name|pic_path**

item_to_characteristic has **id|item_id|characteristic_id**

so for example: for item with id 25 i want to find all its characteristics.

table item_to_characteristics looks like this:

[image: Item_to_characteristic table picture]

So as you see item_to_characteristic hold the id of the item and its characteristics.

This is the query i have writen so far but it doesent return what i want,

```
SELECT item_characteristics.name, item_characteristics.icon_path 
FROM item_characteristics, item_to_characteristics as itch INNER JOIN items
ON items.id=itch.item_id
WHERE items.id=25;
```

The query should return only 5 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have cross joined the table `item_to_characteristics` this is why you are getting more rows than you are expecting. Instead you should inner join to `item_to_characteristics`

```
SELECT  ic.name, ic.icon_path 
FROM    item_characteristics ic
        INNER JOIN item_to_characteristics as itch 
            ON itch.characteristic_id = ic.id
        INNER JOIN items
            ON items.id=itch.item_id
WHERE   items.id = 25;
```

This is one of the reasons I always advise to use ANSI 92 Join syntax, not the ANSI 89 syntax you have used above. Aaron Bertrand has also made a very compelling case to switch in [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).